# How to understand C programming like linguistics - C Library

Tags: c

I am learning C and I'm trying to understand the library.

For example, in The GNU C Library, it gives:

> — Function: char * fgets (char *s, int
>   count, FILE *stream)
>
> The fgets function reads characters
>   from the stream stream up
>   to and including a newline character
>   and stores them in the string s,
>   adding a null character to mark the
>   end of the string. You must supply
>   count characters worth of space in s,
>   but the number of characters read is
>   at most count − 1. The extra character
>   space is used to hold the null
>   character at the end of the string.
>
> If the system is already at end of file
>   when you call fgets, then the
>   contents of the array s are unchanged
>   and a null pointer is returned. A null
>   pointer is also returned if a read
>   error occurs. Otherwise, the return
>   value is the pointer s.
>
> Warning: If the input data has a null
>   character, you can't tell. So
>   don't use fgets unless you know the
>   data cannot contain a null. Don't use
>   it to read files edited by the user
>   because, if the user inserts a null
>   character, you should either handle it
>   properly or print a clear error
>   message. We recommend using getline
>   instead of fgets.

However, I've still seen people use fgets to collect input from console other than a file, eg.:

```
fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
sscanf(line,"%d",&current); // read the input
```

Can someone explain to me how should I read and follow the grammar of the C language?  Should you learn C through imitating others' code or by actually referencing the Library and then writing code yourself?

Cheers,

Comment: Note: what `fgets` and other things do has nothing to do with C grammar, and everything to do with the standard library.

Comment: The getline function that they are talking about[here](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) is a non-standard extension in that particular library.  For portable code you are better off sticking with fgets, I think.

Comment: @jonsca: Well, `getline()` was added to POSIX 2008. Which makes it still non-standard for vanilla c, but standard on unix-alike systems, and `fgets` is horrible.

Comment: @dmckee I always think of portability as being paramount, but I understand your point.  I've never seen the code for getline, so I don't know what ties it to an implementation.  I do, however, think it's important to stress to people new to the language that fgets is superior in safety to gets() or scanf (using %s) without a field width specifier.

Comment: @jonsca: You are certainly right about the improved safety of `fgets`. I have implemented the `getline` semantics using pure c89 library functions, and GNU makes their version available separately of their libc (though obviously under the GPL).

Answer (score 2):

`stdin` *is* a variable of type `FILE *`, it's defined in [`<stdio.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdio.h).
It's used to read data from [standard input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29).